# URL Rewrite not working - IIS 7

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

This is something that we have had working in IIS 6 on Win 2003 but recently we have upgraded our servers to 2008 and IIS 7.5 and for the life of me I cannot get the natively supprted URL rewrite to work.

Under the website (example.site.com) I have setup the following rule:

```
                <rule name="BD">
                    <match url="(.*)" />

                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://new.site.net.au/$1" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^/content/packages/" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
```

We have a sub application that is running under (example.site.com) called "Content" for exmaple.  i.e. https://example.site.com/content/
That sub application launches the following html page with this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var query = window.location.search;
        query += query == "" ? "?" : "&";
        window.location = 'https://' + document.domain + '/Content/Packages/Proxy/Proxy.aspx' + query + 'key=2AB90AC2-7106-4B92-87B1-EAD87E719A48';

    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When this is launched, all I am getting is this: (it is though the URL rewrite isn't even coming into play??

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>   Requested URL: /Content/Packages/Proxy/Proxy.aspx

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Same here. Windows 7 development machine. I'm about to introduce URL rewriting, but IIS (7.5) doesn't appear to ever consider the rules.